# invokeAction is not firing Twilio.FlexWebChat.Actions.on action

Tags: twilio

I'm opening my chat window programtically using ToggleChatVisibility which works great, but it does not fire the relevent FlexWebChat.Action

```
<script>

    const operatingHoursCheckMsg = async function () {

        Twilio.FlexWebChat.Actions.on("afterToggleChatVisibility", (payload) => {
            console.log('Not Working');
        });
    }       

  await initateWebChat.init();
}

function Test() {
 operatingHoursCheckMsg();   
 Twilio.FlexWebChat.Actions.invokeAction("ToggleChatVisibility");    
}

  </script>

 <button type="button" onclick="Test()">Click to open and close chat window</button>
```

the afterToggleChatVisibility event fires if I close and reopen the chat using the chat box ui, but not if I click my button.

How can I trigger this event properly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a race condition causing this issue. You defined the `operatingHoursCheckMsg` function as `async` even though there isn't an asynchronous call involved (though maybe there is in your full script) but in your `Test` function you do not wait for the promise to resolve before invoking the action. I think this means that JavaScript placed the promise on a queue to be handled asynchronously by the event loop, and then ran the next synchronous line of code. So you invoke the action before the event listener is registered.

It also looks as though you want to use the button to continue toggling the chat open and closed, so you should probably not be attaching a new listener every time the button is clicked.

I'd recommend you set up the one listener after you have initiated the webchat, like this:

```html
<script>
  const operatingHoursCheckMsg = async function () {
    // Do operating hours check
  }       

  await initateWebChat.init();

  Twilio.FlexWebChat.Actions.on("afterToggleChatVisibility", (payload) => {
    console.log('Chat toggled!');
  });
}

async function Test() {
  await operatingHoursCheckMsg();   
  Twilio.FlexWebChat.Actions.invokeAction("ToggleChatVisibility");    
}
</script>

<button type="button" onclick="Test()">Click to open and close chat window</button>
```